# JavaScript listen for jQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm having trouble passing an event from jQuery to JavaScript. I am setting the JS event listener first and then firing the jQuery event from an external file, but the listener never gets triggered. Here's some code:

**Listener**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('readyToPlay', loadLibs);

function loadLibs() {
    alert('success');
}

</script>
<script src="/assets/js/plugins/co/co.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Included File** - The alert returns (function), which means jQuery is loaded

```
function init() {
    alert(typeof jQuery);
    $(document).trigger('readyToPlay');
}
```

I am thinking the issue might be caused by referencing document in the external file, but I'm not sure how to get around that.

Comment: Have you created `'readyToPlay'` event before attaching it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: doesn't jQuery already do that with trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use jQuery but you can fire it in Vanilla JS

```
function init() {
  var event= new CustomEvent('readyToPlay',[]);
  document.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.  Still, shouldn't jQuery events be pretty much the same as JavaScript?

Comment: Here the only reason i found, i'm not a real expert of jQuery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885009/jquery-trigger-not-firing-with-bind-or-on-for-custom-events

Comment: @VladislavDimitrov, your answer might be here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41727891/1431728 and also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18901932/1431728